# SQL injection possible after preg_replace?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I am just reviewing a script I want to use for my website. The author filters all user entered data (`$_POST` and `$_GET`) with this function:

```
function XSSCheck($value) {
    return preg_replace(
        array('/&(?!amp;|quot;|nbsp;|gt;|lt;|laquo;|raquo;|copy;|reg;|#[0-9]{1,5};|#x[0-9A-F]{1,4};)/', '/#(?![0-9]{1,5};|x[0-9A-F]{1,4};)/',       '|<|',  '|>|',  '|"|',      "|'|"   ),
        array('&amp;', '&#35;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&#34;', '&#39;'),
        stripslashes($value)
    );
}
```

If I filter a string with that, is it possible to inject into this SQL query for example?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '{$_REQUEST['id']}'
```

I tried it already but did not find out any way to do so. Does anybody know an alternative or is this code secure?

If it is secure, what are the (dis)advantages to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`? Should I change the projects code to the official function?

**EDIT:** You voted down my question, request to close it and sayed the code is bad. But no one has given me any example, how code can be injected! I do not think there is a way.

Comment: Yes, it is very possible. That code is *not* for preventing SQL injection.

Comment: @JohnConde: Why? I think the escape character is prevented...

Comment: You're using MySQLi, so move into the 21st century and use prepared statements/bind variables to prevent SQL injection

Comment: But XSS is nothing to do with SQL Injection

Comment: @MarkBaker: No, **I** am not using MySQLi - the author of the script is :-)

Comment: Value sanitizing is not the best [approach to prevent SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). AFAIK, it should be done with DBMS-driver `escape*` function or. Better approach I might suggest it to use prepared statements.

Comment: @MarkBaker: The function is only named like this - do not know why ;-)

Comment: You specifically mention.... `mysqli_real_escape_string()`! That suggests you're using MySQLi

Comment: You voted down my question, request to close it and sayed the code is bad. But no one has given me any example, how code can be injected! I do not think there is a way.

Comment: RichardReiber, this is because that is a problem solved very long time ago, if you would refer to the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) that @Num6 provided in the comments of my answer, you will see many examples.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: I do not find a injection method for bypassing a `'` filter in a string...

Comment: @RichardReiber still, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/2269749).

Comment: @Num6: What do you want from me? An attacker cannot use this, because  he is in a string, which is started by `'`. In my opinion, there is still no possibility to bypass this. `latin1` is used and MySQL is configured safe. Where the heck should someone inject someone something when using this code?

Comment: If you want to believe that your code is safe, then that's your prerogative.... I just hope any clients that you have realise otherwise.... but be aware that it's possible to SQL inject without injecting a quote into the value

Comment: It's also bad to use `{$_REQUEST['id']}` because you don't know whether the value came from the URL, POST vars, a cookie or where

Comment: If you have two parameters like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE a='$a' AND b='$b'`, you can do this: ```a=\\```, `b= OR 1=1-- `, which results in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE a='\' AND b=' OR 1=1-- '`

Comment: [Same question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/100662/539)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to surely avoid SQL injection (a problem that is older than me) is prepared statements. Any other "escapes" have holes (many theoretical) and should be avoided.

Anyone who is serious about their security will use prepared statements (and not emulated), using "escapes" and such functions as the one you have shown is unprofessional and inconsiderable IMHO.

Comment: Well, if driver-based `escape` function does not guarantee value safeness, then what will?

Comment: @Num6 I'm afraid I'm not the one who can answer this questions. It is not my fault there are security holes in escaping mechanisms, nor can I do anything about it.

Comment: @Num6 it is quite an interesting topic to learn, to be honest. If you are not familiar with it I'd suggest looking into character encodings and how they are being used to bypass escaping functionalities, it is pretty hard to accomplish and on a very deep level but is possible.

Comment: Well, there is still [possibilites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string), yeah. Thanks.

Comment: @Num6 The 2nd answer in the question you linked explains what I meant.